# Почему не создаётся сервис WIndows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, service

Я написал код, который превращает мою программу в службу Windows, но когда я запустил программу с помощью команды `python name_file.py install`, она просто открыла консоль и роботает в ней. Но когда я конвертирую свою программу в exe-файл и создаю сервис через CMD, с помощю команды  `JUSTBOT binpath = "первый путь к name_file.exe второй путь \ name_file.py" DisplayName = "JUSTBOT" start = delayed-auto`. Он создал службу, и она работает, но я не могу запустить ее, и все время когда я пытаюсь её запустить оно выдает ошибку 1053. Пожалуйста, кто-нибудь, помогите мне. Я использую Python 3.7

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import listTT

from time import sleep
import telebot
import sys


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "JUSTBOT"
    _svc_display_name_ = "JUSTBOT"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        #socket.setdefaulttimeout(15)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)



    def SvcRestart(self):
        if servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,'')):
            win32serviceutil.RestartService(self._svc_name_)

        self.main()





    #def SvcDoRun(self):
    #    servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
    #                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
    #                          (self._svc_name_,''))
    #    self.main()

    def main(self):
        while True:
            try:

                listTT.bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=2, timeout=2)
                listTT.bot.infinity_polling(True)








            except Exception:

                pass


            except AttributeError:

                pass

            except ReferenceError:

                pass

            except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:

                pass

            except ConnectionAbortedError:

                pass

            except ConnectionRefusedError:

                pass

            except ConnectionResetError:

                pass

            except RuntimeError:

                pass

            except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:

                pass

            except IndexError:

                pass

            except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:

                pass

            except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.RetryError:

                pass

            except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.Timeout:

                pass

            except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.HTTPError:

                pass

            except RecursionError:

                pass



            finally:

                sleep(6)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(AppServerSvc)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Попробуйте так:**

1. Открыть управление службами Windows.
2. Открыть свойства своей службы.
3. Открыть вкладку: "Вход в систему".
4. Настроить там вход **НЕ** под "Системной учетной записью". (имя пользователя начинается с `.\`)

**Еще вариант:**

Добавить путь к установленному Python в **системный** PATH.

Судя по гуглу:

1. Открыть свойства "Компьютера".
2. Перейти на вкладку: "Дополнительно".
3. Выбрать "Переменные окружения".
4. Выбрать `Path` и нажать "Правка".
5. Добавить путь к файлу `exe` в начало.
6. Все сохранить и закрыть.
7. Возможно, перезагрузить систему.

**Еще вариант:**

Запуск с опцией отладки: `my_service.py debug`

**Еще вариант:**

Использовать [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38768135/6146442) код.

**Еще вариант:**

Использовать `py2exe` для сборки. [Смотри UPDATE.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25770873/6146442)

**P.S.**

Все эти `except * pass`, может заменить на один?

```
except:
    pass
```

Ну или на:

```
except (AttributeError, ReferenceError, ConnectionAbortedError, и прочие):
    pass
```

Comment: частично помогло, оно роботает, но с задержкой. Спасибо большое. + у меня такой. Почему если создавать сервис через `sc` в терминале и первым путем указать на пусть установке Python к `python.exe` а вторым путем указать место где храниться созданый `exe` от скрипта, то оно не роботает. А если сделать первым путем к созданому exe, а вторым путем к самому скрипту, то все чудесно роботает.

Comment: Все потому, что Windows обходит перечисленные пути по очереди. В результате берутся файлы не из твоего проекта.